# How do I select last edited row using a button

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have a project to register customers using a DataGridView and It has 3 buttons:

1. "add" adds the values from the textbox
2. "delete" deletes the selected value in the DataGridView
3. "new" generates the next id number (they're consecutives) and clears all the textboxes fields

I think of adding a button named "cancel" to revert changes generated by the button "new" and it has to select the last edited row and show its cells values in the  textbox.
I made a "cancel" button to select the last row in the list, but the last row in the list is not always the last edited

I'm using Windows Forms, not using a database.

```
private void bttn_cust_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (dgv_customer.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        dgv_customer.Rows[dgv_customer.Rows.Count - 2].Selected = true;
        int i;
        i = dgv_customer.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex;
        txt_cust_clave.Text = dgv_customer.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
        txt_cust_name.Text = dgv_customer.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
        txt_cust_country.Text = dgv_customer.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
    }
    int currentType = Convert.ToInt32(txt_cust_id.Text);
    txt_cust_id.Text = Convert.ToString(--currentType);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a variable or class to hold the index and/or data of the last edited row.  This class would be reinitialized every time the "New" button is pressed.